# Помогите новичку в C++

Tags: c++

При попытке вывода элемента структуры выводится абсолютно другое число (например ввел 2 на выходе получил 40605290)
В чем может быть дело?

```
#include <iostream> 
    #include <stdio.h> 
    using namespace std;
    struct kind_of_sport {
        int wrestling;
        int sprint;
        int powerlifting;
    };
    struct sportsman {
        char surname;
        int age;
        int experience;
        kind_of_sport sport;
    };
    void main(){
        setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
        const int j=2;
        sportsman man[j] = { 0 };
        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
            cout << "Введите фамилию:"<<endl;
            cin >> man[i].surname;
            cout << "Введите возраст:" << endl;
            cin >> man[i].age;
            cout << "Введите стаж:" << endl;
            cin >> man[i].experience;
            cout << "Введите кол-во очков в борьбе:" << endl;
            cin >> man[i].sport.wrestling;
            cout << "Введите кол-во очков в тяжелой атлетике:" << endl;
            cin >> man[i].sport.powerlifting;
            cout << "Введите кол-во очков в беге:" << endl;
            cin >> man[i].sport.sprint;
        }
        cout << man[2].sport.sprint << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
```

Comment: cout << "" - надо точку с запятой.

Comment: Исправил. НЕ помогает

Comment: тогда текст ошибки в студию! :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Функция должна принимать входные параметры. Или говорить о том, что она не принимает ни одного параметра. Вместо

   ```
   int main{
   ```

   должно быть

   ```
   int main() {
   ```
2. Все операторы должны заканчиваться символом `;`. Даже этот `cout << ""`
3. Если Вы сказали, что функция возвращает `int` то она должна его вернуть. `return` я у вас не вижу

Comment: @SHEVA Если мой ответ решил Вашу проблему, отметьте его как верный